# Restrict all Office 365 access externally except for Yammer and Dynamics

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I can currently restrict access to OneDrive/SharePoint (and also Yammer) using Device Access policies, only allowing access to these services when users are inside the corporate network.  However, what I want to achieve is to lock down all services to internal network users only *except* for Yammer and Dynamics (i.e. these should be available everywhere).

We do not have Azure AD Premium in place to create conditional access rules - we also cannot use the ADFS control policies as they are almost block all or allow all - they don't allow us to have the granularity to just permit Yammer and Dynamics and block everything else.

Is anyone aware of any other way to accomplish this?  I was hoping Exchange also had the simple Device Access policies much like OneDrive/SharePoint & Yammer do, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Part of the appeal of moving to Office 365 is in giving users the ability to work from anywhere. Your desire to curtail that ability seems counter-intuitive. Out of curiosity, what's driving this need to restrict the users?

Comment: @joeqwerty There's always one luddite in the administration who thinks that you can only be productive when you are sitting in your chair at the office.